# Open Source testing for SQL Server 2000 and 2005

Tags: sql-server, stress-testing, stress

Are there any open source testing tools for testing the Sql Server 2000 stress .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *free* utilities from Microsoft called [SQLIOSim](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231619) (was SQLIOSTress) to spank the IO system and [OSTRESS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887057) to replay trace files.

Does it have to be Open Source specifically, given you've already agreed to the MS SQL Server licence?

Answer (score 0):

There are two big open source database servers, [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/) and [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/). I would think both of those had some testing tools (although they might need some tweaking in order to be used for ms sql server).